# Dynamic SQL Update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have the following SQL Server 2008 table:

```
ID    Destination     Last Result
01    (555) 319-5170  Disconnect
02    (555) 319-5170  Duplicate
03    (555) 319-5170  Duplicate
04    (555) 261-5000  Duplicate
05    (555) 261-5000  Duplicate
06    (555) 261-7325  Busy
07    (555) 261-7325  Duplicate
08    (555) 261-7345  No Answer
09    (555) 261-7345  Duplicate
```

My goal is to dynamically set the 'Last Result' column for all matching phone numbers. So, in the example table above for Destination((555) 319-5170), the result for all matching phone numbers(555) 319-5170) with the value 'Disconnect'. The sample update statement is below:

```
    UPDATE C
    SET [Last Result] = (
    SELECT Destination
                FROM Call
                WHERE [Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #')
                GROUP BY Destination
                HAVING COUNT(Destination) > 1)
    FROM Call C
    INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT Destination
                FROM Call
                WHERE [Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #')
                GROUP BY Destination
                HAVING COUNT(Destination) > 1
            ) Dup ON Dup.Destination = C.Destination
    WHERE C.[Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #')
```

But I am getting an error:

> *Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

```
**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

ID    Destination     Last Result
01    (555) 319-5170  Disconnect
02    (555) 319-5170  Disconnect
03    (555) 319-5170  Disconnect
04    (555) 261-5000  Duplicate
05    (555) 261-5000  Duplicate
06    (555) 261-7325  Busy
07    (555) 261-7325  Busy
08    (555) 261-7345  No Answer
09    (555) 261-7345  No Answer
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance with a possible solution.

Comment: What is the primary key in the table?

Comment: Is there an identity column on your table? It looks like you're trying to fill-down the last result to cover up 'Duplicate' records. If a number had 'Disconnect', 'Duplicate','No Answer','Duplicate' what would you want the results to be? 'Disconnect','Disconnect','No Answer','No Answer'? Or should they all be 'Disconnect'? Is it even possible to have different non-duplicate [Last Result] values associated with the same number?

Comment: Your error is caused by the fact the subquery on your SET command can return more than one result. You have [Last Result] NOT IN ('Duplicate','No Phone #'), but your sample data shows a greater number of possible options.

Comment: The ID column was added to the table data @Raj More

Comment: @user2051135, your ID column looks like an auto-increment.  So for the phone number `(555) 319-5170` your latest status is actually a *Disconnect*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up the first `Last Result` with the `row_number()` window function. However, there has to be a way to define "first".  In the example, I'm assuming you have an `identity` column:

```
update  t1
set     [Last Result] = t2.[Last Result]
from    Table1 t1
join    (
        select  row_number() over (partition by Destination
                                   order by Id) as rn
        ,        *
        from     Table1
        ) t2
on      t1.Destination = t2.Destination
        and t2.rn = 1;
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01eba/4/0)

If you do not have an identity column, please update the question with how you define "first". There could be a `CreateDt` column for example.

Comment: The ID column was added to the table data. @Andomar

Comment: Thanks for providing this solution. It worked great for the problem that I was trying to solve.